# Why does SharePoint App on-prem need Search:QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal permission but Office 365 does not?

Tags: search, sharepoint-addin, app-permissions

I have an app that already requests `Tenant: Read` permissions in the App Manifest and uses search to find top-level Site Collections (and their sub-sites) in the tenant.   In Office 365 my searches (using REST) work fine with just `Tenant: Read` permissions.  But in the on-prem environment that I have created I need to add/request `Search: QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal` in addition to `Tenant:Read` in the App Manifest.

I thought that `Tenant: Read` would subsume `Search: QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal` but I may have a configuration problem in my on-prem environment.